# case where if SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a script where the on Mondays it pulls back information for Friday, Saturday and Sunday. For Tuesday - Friday, the script will pull back the previous day. Example Tuesday pulls Monday, Wednesday pulls Tuesday, ect.

However, I am having I am having a bit of trouble writing the case.

```
DECLARE @start DATETIME 
DECLARE @end DATETIME

SET @start='2016-05-30'
SET @end=dateadd(dd,1,@start)

Where
orderdate.CreatedDt BETWEEN @start and @end
```

is what I have.

I have found other questions similar, but I do not know how to apply the information. ex: [SQL WHERE depending on day of week](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40803348/sql-where-depending-on-day-of-week)

Comment: What is the goal of that `where` clause? It's not attached to anything.

Comment: Without knowing exactly what you're asking, my best guess is to look into sql's `DATEPART()` function - it can give you a day of the week

Comment: Do you want to update a table or what do you want to achieve?

Comment: This is what happen if you don't know how to ask question.  You end up with more questions instead of answer.  Read this.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I know how to ask questions. I left out all the information in the where because the only line needed was the createdt. that is all I am filtering on. If you are not trying to help then there is no reason to comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this logic based on the day of the week of the current date:

```
SELECT * 
FROM yourtable
WHERE
    yourtable.date BETWEEN
        CASE WHEN datepart(dw, getDate) = 2 THEN GetDate() - 3 ELSE GetDate() - 1 END
        AND
        GETDATE() - 1
```